# Puppet - Set defined types in Nodes.pp

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

How to overwrite defined type in nodes.pp? I want to able to set custom `domain` using `nodes.pp`. `Case Default` isn't an option.

I'm using puppet 6.0..

The following method doesn't work. It says `Could not find declared class resolv::resolv_config`. 
It looks like it used to work in 3.0 according to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/291907/how-to-set-variables-with-basenode-in-nodes-pp).

nodes.pp

```
node "test001" {
  class { 'resolv::resolv_config':
    domain => "something.local",
  }
}
```

modules/resolv/manifests/init.pp

```
class resolv {
    case $hostname {
        /^[Abc][Xyz]/: {
            resolv:resolv_config { 'US':
                domain => "mydomain.local",
            }
        }
    }
}

define resolv::resolv_config($domain){
    file { '/etc/resolv.conf':
        content => template("resolv/resolv.conf.erb"),
    }
}
```

resolv.conf.erb

```
domain <%= @domain %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here, but the one causing the "could not find declared class" error is that you are using the wrong syntax for declaring a defined type. Your code should be something like this:

```
node "test001" {
  resolv::resolv_config { 'something.local':
    domain => "something.local",
  }
}
```

There are examples of declaring defined types in the documentation, https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_defined_types.html.

Once you get that working, you'll find another problem, in that this definition

```
define resolv::resolv_config($domain){
    file { '/etc/resolv.conf':
        content => template("resolv/resolv.conf.erb"),
    }
}
```

will cause a error if you try to declare more than one `resolv::resolv_config`, because they will both try to declare the `/etc/resolv.conf` file resource. You almost certainly wanted to use a [`file_line` resource](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/4.9.1/types#file_line).